# ValueError Python- String to Float for Chi Square

Tags: python, weka, chi-squared

I am running Feature selection using Chi2 code on some data ,the diabetes dataset and the HR dataset from Kaggle. While running the code on diabetes, all is good because the values are all numeric hence are converted to float. But the HR data has string values such as "Job Title" , so Python cannot convert it into a float understandably.

My question is, is there a way I could run such a code on non numeric data to derive feature importance using Chi2 without having to map the string values to numbers?

For those who know WEKA, in WEKA I always run Attribute selection using Chi2 on string data types and it generates the scores but in Python I am stumped.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
data = pd.read_csv("D://Blogs//train.csv")
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range
#apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
#concat two dataframes for better visualization 
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['Specs','Score']  #naming the dataframe columns
print(featureScores.nlargest(10,'Score'))  #print 10 best features
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the non-numeric data to numeric using pandas dataframe [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) method. If the string data aren't structures (e.g. derived from an ENUM) then you may have too many resulting categories to be useful. in that case you'd want to do some cleaning to get everything on the same case, do some stemming of words etc.

Here is a small example of using `get_dummies`

```
import pandas as pd

# create the structure of example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'A', 1, 1.5, 10],
                   [2, 'A', 3.5, 3, 6],
                   [3, 'A', 4, 4, 8],
                   [4, 'A', 4.5, 4.5, 9],
                   [5 ,'A' , 5 , 6 , 10],
                   [1 ,'B' , 1.2 , 1.2 , 4],
                   [3 ,'B' , 4.3 , 4.4 , 8],
                   [4 ,'B' , 4.5 , 4.2 , 7],
                   [2 ,'C' , 3 , 3.3 , 9],
                   [3 ,'C' , 4.2 , 4.1 , 10],
                   ],
                  columns=['ID', 'Name', 'pos_x', 'pos_y', 'volume'])
```

Now you can use the method with the dataframe.

```
>>> df
   ID Name  pos_x  pos_y  volume
0   1    A    1.0    1.5      10
1   2    A    3.5    3.0       6
2   3    A    4.0    4.0       8
3   4    A    4.5    4.5       9
4   5    A    5.0    6.0      10
5   1    B    1.2    1.2       4
6   3    B    4.3    4.4       8
7   4    B    4.5    4.2       7
8   2    C    3.0    3.3       9
9   3    C    4.2    4.1      10

>>> pd.get_dummies(df)
   ID  pos_x  pos_y  volume  Name_A  Name_B  Name_C
0   1    1.0    1.5      10       1       0       0
1   2    3.5    3.0       6       1       0       0
2   3    4.0    4.0       8       1       0       0
3   4    4.5    4.5       9       1       0       0
4   5    5.0    6.0      10       1       0       0
5   1    1.2    1.2       4       0       1       0
6   3    4.3    4.4       8       0       1       0
7   4    4.5    4.2       7       0       1       0
8   2    3.0    3.3       9       0       0       1
9   3    4.2    4.1      10       0       0       1
```

So you see if you have many unique string values in a column of your dataframe you'll get that many additional columns ***per column of strings***.

After you get the results of the `chi2` function you'd then (possibly)
have only a subset of the dummies for a column of the original dataframe. This would give you some more cleaning/grouping to do if the feature(s) will be used in subsequent processing steps.